# How to move sub site and Workflow to another site collection

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, migrate

I have a sub site
In this site have a list which using Sharepoint Workflow (Approval WF)
How can i move this site to another sub site, keep all feature of Sharepoint WF.

Run import/export site can not move sharepoint workflow

Thanks

Comment: Di you try Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite PowerShell commands

Comment: In my case, i need to moving a sub site to new sub site. I thinks Backup/Restore can not do this

Comment: But the question asks about moving a site collection? You should edit the question to reflect exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry :), i edited

Answer (score 0):

You can try ShareGate to migrate the site to another site collection. IMHO this tool is able to migrate also workflows.

Comment: Thanks you but i thinks i can not pay for ShareGate license

Comment: There is also a trial version. However, they mention in the documentation it might not migrate everything (not specified what). But you can try and check whether everything was migrated.

Answer (score 0):

For moving whole site collection, you can also use backup restore....

Comment: In my case, i need to moving a sub site to new sub site. I thinks Backup/Restore can not do this

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not provided robust, native tools to move content between site collections.  You either lose metadata by manually uploading content or lose workflows and similar types of data by using the export/import option.  The best way of accomplishing this is with a third party tool, but as you have mentioned you don't want to do this, it all depends on why you need this site moved and the details surrounding it.  One option, again, depending on your reasons for needing this site moved is...

You could create a new web application (or use an existing web application) and attach a copy of the current content database, remove all the other content so you just have that single sub-site.  Depending on your environment, it may take some effort to make it look similar to the previous site but that should keep the workflow and you would be able to delete it from the original content database at that point.

Comment: But if have 2 sub site with workflow, you need to move 2 sub site in a web application, you can not do by this way